# COUNT() и SUM() в одном запросе с GROUP BY. yii2

Tags: php, sql, yii2

нужно сделать в одном запросе count и sum. запрос примерно такой:

```
UsersPays::find()
    ->where([
        'and',
        ['=', 'users_pays.status', '1'],
        ['=', 'users_pays.active', '1'],
        ['=', 'users_pays.pay_type_id', '1'],
    ])
    ->groupBy('users_pays.card_id')
```

Теперь самое интересное: если я добавляю к запросу `->count('users_pays.id')` или `->sum('users_pays.money)` то считает все нормально. но получается два запроса. yii генерирует что-то вроде этого:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT `users_pays`.* FROM `users_pays` 
WHERE (`users_pays`.`status` = '1') 
  AND (`users_pays`.`active` = '1') 
  AND (`users_pays`.`pay_type_id` = '1') 
GROUP BY `users_pays`.`card_id`) `c`
```

когда в yii пишу так:

```
    UsersPays::find()
    ->select('COUNT(users_pays.id) as count, SUM(users_pays.money) as sum')
    ->where([
        'and',
        ['=', 'users_pays.status', '1'],
        ['=', 'users_pays.active', '1'],
        ['=', 'users_pays.pay_type_id', '1'],
    ])
    ->groupBy('users_pays.card_id')
```

yii генерирует такой запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(users_pays.id), SUM(users_pays.money)
FROM `users_pays` 
WHERE (`users_pays`.`status` = '1') 
  AND (`users_pays`.`active` = '1') 
  AND (`users_pays`.`pay_type_id` = '1') 
GROUP BY `users_pays`.`card_id`
```

в ответе приходит не сумма и количество по всей таблице, а массив с суммой и количеству по каждому `card_id`

подскажите как правильно сделать?

Comment: при чем без group by вариант с `->select(count...)` работает

Comment: Вы сначала разберитесь с запросом, получите правильный результат на SQL, а потом будете его портировать на yii. `в ответе приходит не сумма и количество по всей таблице, а массив с суммой и количеству по каждому card_id` По чему группируете, по тому он и группирует. Если надо по всей таблице - уберите GROUP BY вообще или сделайте `GROUP BY 1`.